# Python - Why does the for loop print the if and else?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

In my code, I choose 3 numbers in my list. Then I want it to see if there are any multiples of 3 in the list. When I run it, it shows all the multiples of 3 but also runs the else too.

How can you only run the else if there is no multiple of 3?

```
array = []

for x in range(3):
    nums = int(input("What are your numbers? "))
    array.append(nums)

print(array)


for i in array:
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print(i, "Is Multiple of 3")

else:
    print("no multiple")
```

run code,

```
What are your numbers? 23
What are your numbers? 33
What are your numbers? 6
[23, 33, 6]
33 Is Multiple of 3
6 Is Multiple of 3
no multiple

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand (or not realize) that `for-else` is a feature of Python

Comment: What exactly you want? If all numbers are not multiple of 3 then should print or if single element is not multiple of 3, then you have to print?

Comment: You need some kind of flag. Before your loop, set the flag to `False`, and inside your `if`, set it to `True`. After your loop, add another `if` to test if your flag is still `False` (ie you never found a multiple).

Comment: You could use `if not any(x % 3 == 0 for x in array): print() else: ...`